# What is wrong/missing from the process subsystem?

Tags: component-selection, optoelectronics

[image: Picture of my block diagram]

My teacher told me to reconsider the process subsystem but I'm not sure what is really missing from it.
background story: when a guy is standing on the porch, the LED lights up

Comment: It's a bit light on for detail. You have input from an IR diode. Saying the process is 'photodiode' says nothing. How about amplification, bandpass filtering, demodulation. Read up about the 'underpants gnomes'.

Comment: Talk to your teacher is the best advice.

Comment: i talked to him all he said was
What is the meaning of a system?
What is the meaning of a subsystem?
Does a LED makes up a subsystem
does the photo diode alone makes up the input subsystem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

First focus on the interfaces :

assuming "IR diode" means IR LED, the interface into the process subsystem is an IR light signal of some intensity (How much? Background story tells you something : What signal do you get bouncing off a person standing on a porch, or blocked by a person standing in front of the IR LED?)

Then the interface to the output subsystem (LED) is a specified current over some range of voltages. (What current? what voltages?) How should the current change in different system states, like presence/absence of person, daylight or night time, presence of cat, raccoon, crow etc on porch?

Given these interfaces, the process subsystem is the block between them.

While one component in that subsystem is a photodiode, it should be obvious that a photodiode alone just won't do it, you need some other stuff as well (unless you expect the photodiode to act as a powerful enough solar cell to drive the LED by itself!)

So, yes you do need to reconsider the process subsystem.

Comment: could you explain more on what does this mean? "unless you expect the photodiode to act as a powerful enough solar cell to drive the LED by itself"

Comment: A solar cell is merely a big photodiode, and any photodiode can create some power from light incident on it. But in this circumstance, nowhere nearly enough.